# Need a lua script to convert text into the utf8 encoding string

Tags: utf-8, lua

I want to create a lua script which will convert text to utf8 encoded string.
The problem is I am using lua version 5.2 which does not support LUAJit which are having libraries to do so.
So, I need a function which will do this task for me.
For example I will pass "hey this is sam this side" it should give me the utf8 encoded string like "\x68\x65\x79\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x73\x61\x6d\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x73\x69\x64\x65"

The requirement is like that need to use lua only.

Comment: Just a reminder - that's not utf8 encoding, that's escaping hex values in a string literal. It has nothing to do with utf.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
local str = "hey this is sam this side"
local answer = string.gsub(str,"(.)",function (x) return string.format("\\x%02X",string.byte(x)) end)
print(answer)
```

The answer is:

```
"\x68\x65\x79\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x73\x61\x6D\x20\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x73\x69\x64\x65"
```